# trigger ko validation error manually

Tags: ajax, validation, knockout-validation

This email form has front-end validation which merely checks that it contains a '@'. If it fails, it turns on the error message 'Wrong format'.

If it passes, then the ajax call hits a back-end API end-point which performs a more rigorous regex on it. i.e. foo@bar will pass front-end validation but fail back-end validation.

If the ajax result comes back as ValidationError this means it's failed the back-end 'valid pattern' test. In this case, I want to manually trigger the existing front-end 'bad pattern' error message.

How can I do this from within the javascript? is there a variable or flag I can set from within "case ValidationError:" that will do this?

My form:

```
<form novalidate data-bind="submit: onRegister">
<div class="input-wrapper email" data-bind="validationElement: EmailAddress, css: { 'validation-success': EmailAddress.isModified() && EmailAddress.isValid() }">
    <label for="registerModalEmail">@AuthenticationStrings.EmailLabel</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="registerModalEmail" name="EmailAddress" data-bind="value: EmailAddress" required />
</div>  
<div class="validation-error-message" id="email-address-error" data-bind="validationMessage: EmailAddress"></div>
<button>Create Account</button>
```

My script:

```
self.EmailAddress = ko.observable().extend({
    required: {
        params: true,
        message: 'Please provide an email'
    },
    pattern: {
        /**
            * Email validation is crazy, so just checking for @ symbol on front end.
            * Back end will use a more complex regex.
            */
        params: '@',
        message: 'Bad pattern'
    },
    validation: {
        async: true,
        validator: function (val, parms, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/isEmailAllowed',
                data: { 'EmailAddress': val },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (results) {
                    if (results) {
                        switch (results.result) {
                        case "Valid":
                            callback(true); // email is unique
                            break;
                        case "ValidationError":
                            // email is malformed
                            // might be caught by front-end but can slip through
                            break;
                        default:
                            callback(false);// unknown error
                        }
                    }
                }//,
                //error: function (xhr) {
                //    if (xhr) {
                //        switch (xhr.statusText) {
                //        case "Conflict":
                //            callback(false); // show dupe email message
                //            break;
                //        default:
                //            callback(true); // defeat usual error message
                //            // trigger invalid email error
                //        }
                //    }
                //}
            });
        },
        message: 'This email exists. Sign in instead.'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try an email validation rule `.extend({email:true}):` and you will get a proper email validation working out of box :)

If you still want to have an external validation then take a look at async rules, as they were made to handle this case: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Async-Rules

Answer (score 0):

If the validation isn't part of your submit method, then you are still essentially doing client side validation. I would tend to agree that using the native knockout.js email rule would be functionally equivalent.

If you build the validation into your submit method, then you would gain the additional security of the client not being able to circumvent your validation.

Have your webmethod return a dataobject that indicates whether the submit was sucessful or not:

```
    public class JSONResponse
    {
        public JSONResponse()
        {
            ErrorLevel = (int)Enums.ErrorLevel.SUCCESS;
        }

        public object Data { get; set; }
        public string BasicErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public int ErrorLevel { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static JSONResponse SubmitEmail(string emailAddress)
    {
        var response = new JSONResponse();
        try
        {
            if (validateEmail(emailAddress))
            {
                SubmitEmail(emailAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                response.ErrorLevel = (int)PDSI.PRISM.DataObjects.Enums.ErrorLevel.FATAL;
                response.BasicErrorMessage = "Email format is incorrect";
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.ErrorLevel = (int)PDSI.PRISM.DataObjects.Enums.ErrorLevel.FATAL;
            response.BasicErrorMessage = "Unhandled error";
        }
    }
```

Client knows how to behave based on what error level is passed back from the server:

```
    self.EmailAddress = function()
    {
        var callback = function (response) {
            if (response.ErrorLevel == ErrorLevel.SUCCESS) {
                //yay cake, move to next screen?
            }
            else {
                alert(response.BasicErrorMessage);
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/SubmitEmail',
            data: { 'emailAddress': val },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                callack(response);
            }
        });
    }
```